# What type of chart or canvas using they are?

Tags: image, canvas, browser, web, charts

http://www.evolutionoftheweb.com/

Question is:

What type of chart plugin they used in JavaScript like jqplot, float plugin?
If not, then how did they make it? is it just image or canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the page source you will find that all the logic is in the /js/all.js file. If you search this you can find things like: jquery, d3, and other libraries. It seems that majority of work is done with d3.